# Iterating over an ArrayList Always misses 1 entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

When iterating over an ArrayList of strings to display on my WebForm using Razor one entry is never actually displayed.

The code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TweetUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%           
            ArrayList alList = GetLatest();
        %>
        <ul>
            <%
              foreach (string tweet in alList)
              {
            %>
            <li>
                <asp:Literal ID="thisLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <% thisLiteral.Text = tweet; %>
            </li>    
            <%    
              } 
             %>
        </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

There is nothing in the timer event it is just used to refresh the updatepanel
So if alList contains 4 items this is displayed.
 - tweet 1
 - tweet 2
 - tweet 3

where tweet 1 - 3 are actual tweets.
Can anyone see the problem in the code?

Comment: What is this horror ? You are not using Razor. You are integrating data logic into your view. It's a hodgepodge of different technics, none of them being supposed to interact with each other.

Comment: What does `GetLatest()` do?

Comment: Gets the alList which is populated by a Twitter Stream

Comment: What is in alList? All items?

Comment: 4 tweets, only 3 are being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <asp:Literal ID="thisLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <% thisLiteral.Text = tweet; %>
```

Wow, that is quite clever. I have never seen that. I don't think it's a good idea to modify ASP.NET controls within code nuggets on the page.

The order of those two statements is reversed. That is the bug.

But *much* better would be:

```
 <%= tweet %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not Razor. You are mixing different ways of doing stuff, and none of them right.

- The data retrieval should be either in code-behind, or in a DataSource.
- You are creating multiple ASP.Net literals with the same ID
- You should use a data repeater to do this kind of stuff

Something more along the lines of this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TweetUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="thisLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Literal>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

And in your code behind, on page load:

```
this.Repeater1.DataSource = GetLatest();
```